# Is there a way to get a list of Youtube videos sorted by view count

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, data-science, youtube-data-api, data-mining

I am trying to collect a large list of YouTube's most watched videos for a data science application. I tried to use the YouTube Data API with the following query:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search&order=viewCount&type=video&regionCode=US&key=API_KEY`,

but it does not seem to give me the same video ideas as in this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-viewed_YouTube_videos

Could someone tell me how I should do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint is one way to search for the most viewed videos pertaining to a given region.

There's another endpoint -- [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) -- that, when queried with `chart` set to `mostPopular`, gives back:

> [**`chart`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#chart) (string)
>
> The `chart` parameter identifies the chart that you want to retrieve.
>
> Acceptable values are:
>
> `mostPopular` – Return the most popular videos for the specified [content region](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#regionCode) and [video category](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#videoCategoryId).

As per the specification of `videoCategoryId`:

> By default, charts are not restricted to a particular category.

Therefore, you may safely invoke `Videos.list` with `chart=mostPopular` and `regionCode=US`, without passing to it any `videoCategoryId`.

These two are the only API means that accomplish the task described by your post.

Comment: I understand, but my query was not returning the correct results. It should have contained the videos in the 'most viewed videos' on wikipedia.

Comment: @LeoTheDev, With respect to accuracy, I would not oppose the data published by Wikipedia against data provided by Google's own API. But, in any case, you may address this issue directly to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: The top video returned by my query had only 14 million views, as opposed to the top video on Youtube having more than 6 billion views

Comment: I tried the Videos.list endpoint, and although it gave videos with more views, it was still not even close to reality as I don't think the mostPopular chart is calculated by view count alone. I think I'll just use a crawler and then sort the videos.

Comment: I noticed myself the video [`XqZsoesa55w`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqZsoesa55w) (which has 8.7 billion views according to Google's API and to YouTube's website), but which is not returned within the first page of `Videos.list` queried with `chart=mostPopular`, even within its own category (that with ID `27`). Is this a bug of the API? I'd recommend to report this to Google.